# Yii2 ЧПУ ссылающийся на url с GET параметром

Tags: yii2, url-manager

Помогите сделать ЧПУ в Yii2 вида

```
...
'rules' =>[
    '/uslugi' => '/Pages/view/id/1'
],
...
```

В строке `'/Pages/view/id/1'` `Pages` - контроллер, `view` - action, `id` - параметр, `1` - значение параметра `id`.

На Yii1 эта конструкция работала, а вот в Yii2 - нет.

Дело в том, что эти правила должны создаваться по мере добавления страниц с админки. ЧПУ хранятся в таблице и подтягиваются динамически.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что требуется. Почитайте документацию по urlManager, возможно некоторые вопросы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Мне нужно написать ЧПУ не просто для конкретного action, а для action-а с определенным параметром. Т.е. если '/uslugi' => 'pages/view' - работает и ссылается просто на action, а '/uslugi' => '/pages/view/id/1' - нет. В Yii1 работали простые правила - ключем правила указывал что угодно (тот адрес который хотел видеть в результате), а значением - полный маршрут, включая id записи. Хочется, чтобы и в Yii2 так получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу следующим образом. Так как у меня ЧПУ хранятся в таблице, в правила я добавил

```
...
    [
      'class'=>\frontend\components\CpuRules::class,
    ],
...
```

`\frontend\components\CpuRules` это интерфейс и имеет он след. содержание:

```
class CpuRules implements \yii\web\UrlRuleInterface {
    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params){}
    public function parseRequest($manager, $request){
        $url = trim($request->pathInfo, '/');
        $search = Cpu::find()->andWhere(['readable'=>$url])->one();
        if(count($search) == 0)
            return false;
        return [$search->original,Json::decode($search->original_params)];
    }
}
```

В таблице ЧПУ я храню маршрут (пр. `'pages/view'`), параметры маршрута в Json (пр. `{"id":1}`) и читабельный вид маршрута (пр. `'/uslugi'`).
В `parseRequest` я написал собственную обработку запросов исходя из своих нужд (ищется читабельный маршрут в таблице и если удается его найти - возвращаем оригинальный маршрут с параметрами). Это то, что касается обработки запроса. По этой же логике можно описать метод `createUrl`.

Источник: https://dev-tips.ru/blog/post/yii2-napisanie-pravil-razbora-i-postroeniya-url